# Intel | Mcafee True Key software / chrome extension not working

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, encryption, password-management

I noticed that Intel True Key chrome extension not working from last 24 hours. So, I removed the extension and then tried to install windows software from their website (https://www.truekey.com).

When I run the setup .exe file after download, there appears to be an only blank white screen. I tried Restarts, Repeated execution of the file but nothing worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below steps:

1. Clear complete 'chrome' browser history.
2. Now, install the latest True Key chrome extension.

To install, download the respective crx from 
[Click Here](https://www.crx4chrome.com/crx/14061/)​ ​

Next, open extensions window / tab in browser then drap and drop the downloaded file on to it.

It will be installed automatically by this. You can start using True Key as usual.

Comment: It isn't recommended that you download software from untrusted/unverified sites.